# Kubernetes Service NodePort not connected

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-service

I am using minikube on windows 10. And I generate kubernetes NodePort Service to access from client web browser. First the below codes are resources configuration file.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: blog-system 
  labels:
    app: blog-pod 
spec:
  containers:
  - name: blog-app
    image: app:latest 
    imagePullPolicy: Never 
    ports:
      - containerPort: 8080
    args: ["-t", "-i"]
  - name: blog-mysql
    image: mysql:latest 
    env:
      - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
        value: password
      - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
        value: password
      - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
        value: test
    ports:
      - containerPort: 3306

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: blog-app-svc
spec:
  type: NodePort   
  selector:
    app: blog-pod  
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
    nodePort: 31000
```

The Kubernetes pods and services are generated successfully.

```
> kubectl get services
NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
blog-app-svc   NodePort    10.100.32.119   <none>        8080:31000/TCP   79s
kubernetes     ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          5m54s

> minikube service blog-app-svc --url
http://192.168.5.25:31000
```

However the access to this kubernetes nodeport service is rejected even with all of these urls.

```
http://10.100.32.119:31000
http://10.100.32.119:8080
http://192.168.5.25:31000
```

I have no idea where the errors are on the resources configuration file, service part or pod part. Any idea, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `targetPort` of your Service doesn't match the `containerPort` of your Pod.

Your Service declaration says that `nodePort` 31000 on any node in the cluster, or `port` 8080 on the special host name `blog-app-svc.default.svc.cluster.local` within the cluster, forwards to `targetPort` 80 in some pod with an `app: blog-pod` label.  You have that pod, but it's listening to ports 8080 and 3306 and not port 80.

If you swap `port` and `targetPort` then the default HTTP port 80 on the Service will forward to port 8080 in your pod, which is probably what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the configuration is correct for your NodePort. Some advice for troubleshooting is that this is likely caused by a firewall running on your Kubernetes Worker Node.

So ensure that 31000 is open and you should be able to resolve that IP from the Kubernetes API Server.

<strike>Secondly, you should look into adding a [LoadBalancer controller](https://metallb.universe.tf/installation/) to your cluster so you don't have to use NodePorts. They're not really used for anything other than debugging.</strike>

Comment: Good point, my mistake. I have a dedicated server at home so I rarely use Minikube.